# Error when changing from OpenCV 4.5.1 to 3.4.0

Tags: c++, opencv

I am working on a C++ program using opencv that computed the surface area ratio occupied by objects in an image. The objects are mapped to black pixels and then the number of black pixels in the image is evaluated.

My programming environment is Windows 10, using Visual Studio 2019.

The code was working as specified when I was using opencv 4.5.1. However, due to execution environment restrictions I have been requested to change to opencv 3.2.0. After making the appropriate changes in my project the source code compiled as is, but now I get a “Unhandled exception at ... Microsoft C++ exception: std::length_error at memory location ...” when my code calls cv::drawContours

```
double run_calc_2d_occupancy(bool room_canvas_done, double x_min, double y_max, double pixel_size, cv::Mat& room_canvas, cv::Mat& obj_canvas, unsigned long long& num_pixels_room, unsigned long long& num_pixels_obj) {
    
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> room_polygons = {};
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> object_polygons = {};
        int idx_type = DBFGetFieldIndex(*m_hDBF_p, "type");
    
        for (int i = 0; i < m_num_entities; i++) {
    
            SHPObject* p_object_i = SHPReadObject(*m_hSHP_p, i);
            std::vector<cv::Point> polygon_i = object_to_polygon(p_object_i);
    
            std::string value_type_i = DBFReadStringAttribute(*m_hDBF_p, i, idx_type);
            bool room_check = !room_canvas_done && (value_type_i == "wall" || value_type_i == "ceiling" || value_type_i == "floor");
            if (room_check) {
                room_canvas_done = true;
                room_polygons.push_back(polygon_i);
            }
            else if (value_type_i == "object") {
                object_polygons.push_back(polygon_i);
            }
        }
    
        SHPClose(*m_hSHP_p);
        DBFClose(*m_hDBF_p);
    
        // error occurs here
        cv::drawContours(obj_canvas, object_polygons, -1, cv::Scalar(0), -1);
        cv::drawContours(room_canvas, room_polygons, -1, cv::Scalar(0), -1);
    
        unsigned long long total_number_of_pixels = (unsigned long long)obj_canvas.rows * (unsigned long long)obj_canvas.cols;
        num_pixels_obj = total_number_of_pixels - cv::countNonZero(obj_canvas);
    
        num_pixels_room = total_number_of_pixels - cv::countNonZero(room_canvas);
    
        return num_pixels_room != 0 ? num_pixels_obj / (double)num_pixels_room : 0.0;
    }
```

The code used to initialize *obj_canvas* and *room_canvas* is as follows

```
cv::Mat set_canvas() {
    unsigned long x_len = (unsigned long)(std::ceil(m_pixel_coeff * (m_x_max - m_x_min)));
    unsigned long y_len = (unsigned long)(std::ceil(m_pixel_coeff * (m_y_max - m_y_min)));
    return cv::Mat(y_len + 2 * m_padding, x_len + 2 * m_padding, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255.));
}
```

I tried using the debug functionality in Visual Studio to find out where the error was taking place. I was lead into types.hpp, but with no further insight. The error seems to be taking place at

```
template<typename _Tp> inline
Point_<_Tp>::Point_()
    : x(0), y(0) {}
```

As mentioned the code was working with opencv 4.5.1, but gives the stated error when changing to opencv 3.2.0. Any advice on how to solve or approach this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that the functions you use were existing in 3.2.0? With same signature? Because maybe you still have the headers for 4.5.1 on your machine (so it compiles) but linking with 3.2 generates some run time failure.

Comment: The function that I am using is also in opencv 3.2.0, with the same signature. It is possible that there might be a problem when linking the libraries.

Comment: Another possible reason could be that your code introduces undefined behavior somewhere, and that this UB only manifests as a crash when downgrading to 3.2